# What causes this popup in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a simple tool for my job. It involves opening a file dialog box, selecting a file, opening it, analyzing it for different items, then creating a new workbook with the results. This is all done with VBA macros, activated via a command button.

The code works fine, all does what it's supposed to. However, at the start when the file dialog box is first opened, sometimes this error message pops up:

[image]

It doesn't affect the code or how it runs whatsoever, but it is a bit of a nuisance. There is no further detail provided for this "error". Does anyone know what might cause this popup?

Comment: An error occuring is usually the cause of such a message more can't really be said. How about posting the relevant part of your code?

Comment: I have come across this before. I ended up having to recreate the document as a new file.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That's the thing, it's not necessarily one piece of code that does it. Most often, it's when I go to open a file. But it will appear randomly.

Comment: What about this?

Application.DisplayAlerts = False